# Override an inner interface class variable with outer class variable in python

Tags: python, class, abstract

I am facing the following dilemma ...

```
class XCEngine:

    def __init__(self, year, xrules=None):
        self.year = year
        if xrules is None:
            xrules=[]
        self.xrules = xrules         #<------- set rules[] with this

    class Xchange(AbstractHolidayCalendar):    # abstract interface reference
        rules = []                   #<------- need to dynamically set the rules[]


    # Below is how I'm using the above snippet:

    def compute(self):
            date_index = XCEngine.Xchange().holidays(dt.datetime(self.year - 1, 12, 31), dt.datetime(self.year, 12, 31))
            date_index3 = date_index.to_native_types().tolist()
            return date_index3
```

How can I set the `rules[]` list inside the abstract interface `Xchange`?

I am trying to have `rules[]` replaced with `self.xrules`

[UPDATED]
[Added the following function to `XCEngine`]

```
def ruleswriter(self):
    XCEngine.Xchange().rules = self.xrules
```

[Then, creating the object and calling as:]

```
def something():
    some = [USMartinLutherKingJr]
    XCEngine.ruleswriter(some)
    print XCEngine(2017).compute()

something()
```

[Throws me the following error]:

```
(venv_OpenRefine) localhost@xcEngine $ python xcEngine.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "xcEngine.py", line 54, in <module>
    something()
File "xcEngine.py", line 51, in something
    XCEngine.ruleswriter(some)
TypeError: unbound method ruleswriter() must be called with XCEngine instance as first argument (got list instance instead)
```

Comment: This reminds me of Java. o_o

Comment: I'm not sure I understand when you want to "dynamically set the rules[]". Both classes are defined up front. There's no new definition of `Xchange` for each instance of `XCEngine`, all instances share the same class (just like they share other class variables). You can of course modify the class variables at any time (such as in `XCEngine.__init__`), but I'm not sure if that's what you want or not.